# How to use checkbox input to filter results?

Tags: angularjs

I want to give the user the ability to only see maps witha color value of 'true' in the ng-repeat results if he chooses the "Only show color maps" checkbox.

Here's my code:

```
<section class="form-group">
    <label>Sort By:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="orderProp">
                        <option value="title">Title</option>
                        <option value="filename">File Name</option>
                        <option value="class">Classification</option>
                    </select>
 </section>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="color"> Only show color maps
                </label>
```

Here is my view:

```
<tr ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in filtered = (mapData | filter: query | orderBy:orderProp" ng-show="orderProp !== 'color || item.color">
                    <td>{{item.class}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.filename}}</td>
                </tr>
```

The data is coming from a JSON file with a 'color' key with a value of either *true* or *false*.

My controller code is:

```
mapApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('js/MOCK_DATA.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.mapData = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = "title";
}]);
```

Here's a **[live demo of the page](http://ogmda.com/symbols/index.html)**

Comment: Sorry, here's what was missing from the code: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.color"
                 ng-true-value="'color'">Only show color maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the ng-model to the select box:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input ng-model="showColor" type="checkbox" value="color"> Only show color maps
</label>
```

Then, remove the ng-show:

```
<tr ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in filtered = (mapData | filter: query | orderBy: [orderProp,'title'])">
        <td>{{item.class | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.filename}}</td>                        
</tr>
```

Finally, change the controller to this:

```
mapApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  var fullData = [];
  $http.get('js/MOCK_DATA.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.mapData = data;
    fullData = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = "title";
  //Filter data when check the checkbox
  $scope.$watch('showColor', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
         $scope.mapData = fullData.filter(function(item) { return item.color;});
    } else {
         $scope.mapData = fullData;
    }
  });

}]);
```